# Программа для нахождения кубического корня числа

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я написал программу, которая находит кубический корень числа. Например, когда я ввожу 8, должно вывести 2, но выводит 3. Почему?

```
# Почему программа увеличивает результат на один?
num = int(input(""))
x = 1
root = x**3
while root < num:
     root = x**3
     x += 1

print(x-1)
```

Comment: Потому что вы сперва вычисляете 2**3, а потом прибавляете x+=1 и из-за этого получается 3 вместо 2. Вам нужно поменять эти два действия местами

Comment: А вообще `print(num ** (1/3))`